# Error : DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: The Appx package's manifest is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080204)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

hen I deployed my app on phone 8.1 I am getting this error

> Error : DEP0001 : Un expected Error: The Appx package's manifest is
>   invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080204)

My appmanifest page lookslike this.Someone help me in resolving this error.

Thanks in advance.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <Package
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
      xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
      xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
      IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp">

      <Identity
        Name="a9b39f41-405f-4f3c-b952-b1074c374308"
        Publisher="CN=jk"
        Version="1.0.0.0" />

      <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="a9b39f41-405f-4f3c-b952-b1074c374308" PhonePublisherId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"/>

      <Properties>
        <DisplayName>networking2</DisplayName>
        <PublisherDisplayName>jk</PublisherDisplayName>
        <Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
      </Properties>

      <Dependencies>
        <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.10069.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.10069.0" />
      </Dependencies>

      <Resources>
        <Resource Language="x-generate"/>
      </Resources>

      <Applications>
        <Application Id="App"
          Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe"
          EntryPoint="networking2.App">
          <uap:VisualElements
            DisplayName="networking2"
            Square150x150Logo="Assets\Logo.png"
            Square44x44Logo="Assets\SmallLogo.png"
            Description="networking2"
            BackgroundColor="#464646">
            <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
          </uap:VisualElements>
        </Application>
      </Applications>

      <Capabilities>
        <Capability Name="internetClient" />
      </Capabilities>
    </Package>
```

Comment: Thanks to all who tried to answer me. The problem got resolved when I updated my phone from windows 8.1 to windows 10 preview.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who tried to answer me. The problem got resolved when I updated my phone from windows 8.1 to windows 10 preview